Remnants in the registry
Did the registry of Windows XP contain different keys for helping programs port from Windows 9x and Windows NT linages? So for example, were there two "parallel" keys one with "NT" in the name and one without?
Or was there application compatibility features or other reasons meaning this was unnecessary?
Edit: Given the information provided by @dave I have asked the wrong question, below is a new one.
How did the Windows NT registry differ from the consumer lineage of Windows when it was introduced?
If software needed to query the "software" tree how did it distinguish between "Windows" versus "Windows NT"? Did this need to be a literal path or was there an API to automate the choice.
Lastly, what does REGEDT32.EXE
do compared with REGEDIT.EXE?

“Remnants in the registry” what?

@user3840170 This was an attempt at a fun title.

This is multiple questions.  Some show little research - registry keys have pathnames just like files do.

(Answered from memory)
Any program could create any key under any name, so there is no general principle here.
But in general, if a program would run under consumer Windows or Windows NT, there would be no need to have two sets of settings.  What would be the benefit?
The only significant case I know about is "Windows" versus "Windows NT", in the "software" tree, but that dates from very early NT anyway, and once you've done that, it's hard to undo without creating compatibility problems.
Even then, I think the OS only used "Windows NT" for configuring things that had no counterpart in consumer Windows.
